# Does std::string::clear and std::list::clear erases data from memory

Tags: c++, string, list

In the description of the string::clear function, it says:

> **clear:** Erases the contents of the string, which becomes an empty string (with a length of 0 characters).

In the description of the list::clear function, it says:

> **clear:** Removes all elements from the list container (which are destroyed), and leaving the container with a size of 0.

Does the clear overwrite the memory of the string and the list or just free them?

Comment: Neither free the memory. C++11 provides a `shrink_to_fit` member function that at least *requests* the implementation to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray: I would be surprised if `std::list` did not release the memory on `clear()`... you are probably thinking about `std::vector` instead

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - the implementation is allowed to cache list nodes for future reuse. Seems to me that Rogue Wave's library did a lot of this.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Right, our own implementation does that, but conceptually the memory has been released. There is no `shrink_to_fit` that can help here for lists either, as the nodes would still be cached by the library.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - this is probably getting hypertechnical, but the distinction I'm getting at is that when you "free" memory it generally means that the memory goes back to the free store, and is available for reuse anywhere in the program; releasing it to a node cache makes it available for same-size nodes, but not for general use. That's undoubtedly **not** the point of this question. `<g>`

Comment: @PeteBecker: agreed that this might not be the point of this particular question, and at any rate there is a lot of handwaving if you want to consider what really happens. For example, memory that is freed need not be released to the OS, it might not even be usable inside the same process for a different size allocation depending on the implementation that manages memory (the page might have been marked for a particular size of allocations). Of course, a cache inside a particular container is even more limited than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The memory isn't overwritten. It is not even guaranteed to be freed.

For example, if you create a huge string and call `clear` on it, only its size will be reduced, but the allocated memory may still be reserved. However, it will be freed if the string gets out of scope.

`std::list` at least guarantees that the elements inside the list will be destructed if you clear the list.

So, if your memory contains sensitive data, you should manually overwrite them.

Answer (score 11):

Neither function is required to overwrite the erased data.

Comment: +1 In fact, in a release build I would assume it is not overwritten.